# Is there any way to fetch the list of resource types available for a patient id from FHIR Server?

Tags: java, hl7-fhir, hapi-fhir, smart-on-fhir

I want the fetch the list of resource types available for a patient from the FHIR server. I tried to fetch the List of items from the Patient. But it doesn't contain all the resource types available for that particular patient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say "the list of resource types available for a patient from the FHIR server", I think what you mean is the resource types that can be searched by patient on the FHIR server.

To build such a list, read the FHIR server's `CapabilityStatement`.  Iterate through the CapabilityStatement's `resource` array, checking each item's `searchParam` array for an element where `name` = 'patient' and `type` = 'reference'. If you find it, add that item's `type` value (i.e. the resource type) to the list.

Answer (score 1):

http://hapi.fhir.org/baseR4/metadata

http://wildfhir4.aegis.net/fhir4-0-1/metadata

https://vonk.fire.ly/R4/metadata

I think you're asking this.

If you examine any of the reference implementations above: you'll retrieve the CapabilityStatement.

EVERY FHIR server must supply a CapabilityStatement.

You look at the CapabilityStatement, find the Fhir-Resource ("Patient" here), and then any includes and rev-includes.

```
                "type": "Patient",

                "searchInclude": [
                    "Patient:general-practitioner",
                    "Patient:link",
                    "Patient:organization"
                ],
                "searchRevInclude": [
                    "Account:patient",
                    "Account:subject",
```

also see:

https://www.hl7.org/fhir/search.html#include

Comment: I don't think this will work.  Checking `searchInclude` and `searchRevInclude` on the Patient resource in the `CapbilityStamment` will only tell you what type of searching is supported.  If not supported, it doesn't mean the resource type isn't accessible though other means.  As an example, look at the CapabilityStatement of smarthealthit.org: https://launch.smarthealthit.org/v/r4/fhir/metadata. The patient resource doesn't support `searchRevInclude` and only lists 3 items in `searchInclude`.  There are plenty of other patient related resources implemented there.

Comment: I don't think"will not work" is the correct sentiment.  I think "is part of an approach" and "by itself is not complete".  Your answer would be a part as well (a better part).   Include/RevIncludes are desirable from a how many times I have to hit the fhir-server.  Your approach is more complete in a "find as much as you can".  I can see some pros and cons to both.     I'm not sure if you downvoted the answer, but a downvote is usually a "totally off base" answer.  My answer is "on base", just maybe not the best answer.  Please don't punish people for trying to help people by downvoting.

Comment: Another way to state this.  When we (my team and I) are consuming FHIR-Resources from another FHIR-Server.... we try (patient $everything) first (but very few other fhir-servers have this) THEN we try INCLUDE/REVINCLUDE (because of less hits to the fhir-server, but we still get the data) THEN we try /Encounter?patient=p123, etc, etc.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstood the question, but I thought it was just about trying to understand what FHIR resources that have been implemented and are searchable by patient -- which requires a one time parsing of the CapabilityStatement to answer.  I see your point and perhaps I was two hasty with a downvote.  I would undo, but SO says two much time has elapsed and I am unable to unless the answer is edited.

Comment: the original question is ambiguous.  "resource types available for a patient from the FHIR server" I interpreted it one way (what might be INCL/REVINC with a patient), and you interpreted it as "fhir-resources searchable with a patient-filter".   So (belaboring the point)...my answer was not "off base", it was a different interpretation of the ambiguous description. If anything, I added some value to this question (not only for the single original asker, but future readers of SOF) in the idea of "hey, go look at the capability statement, if nothing else". I have (artificially) edited my answer

Answer (score 1):

I think what your asking is resources types linked to a Patient. In this case you can do a http://base/fhir/Patient/[id]/$everything

https://hl7.org/fhir/operation-patient-everything.html

Comment: I guess $everything is not supported by all the FHIR servers

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for posting your answers. I have achieved this by making a batch request like the below,

```
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

    bundle.setType(Bundle.BundleType.TRANSACTION);

    // Adding bundle entries to make the batch request

    // To fetch the resource count for each resource type

    for (String resource : resources) {

        String url = String.format(MyConstants.URLs.FETCH_SUMMARY_COUNT, 
        resource, patientId);

 bundle.addEntry().getRequest().setUrl(url).setMethod(Bundle.HTTPVerb.GET);

    }

    try {

        // Create a client

        IGenericClient client = fhirContext.newRestfulGenericClient(fhirServerUrl);

        BearerTokenAuthInterceptor bearerTokenAuthInterceptor = new BearerTokenAuthInterceptor(accessToken);

        client.registerInterceptor(bearerTokenAuthInterceptor);



        bundle = client.transaction().withBundle(bundle).execute();

        IFhirPath iFhirPath = fhirContext.newFhirPath();

        List<IntegerType> counts = iFhirPath.evaluate(bundle, MyConstants.FHIRPATH.SUMMARY_COUNT_FROM_BUNDLE,

                IntegerType.class);

        ResourceTypesResponse resourceTypesResponse = ResourceParser.getResourceTypes(counts, resources);

        if (resourceTypesResponse == null) {

            throw new PatientNotFoundException("Resource Not Found");

        }

        return resourceTypesResponse;

    } catch (Exception e) {

        if (e.getMessage().equalsIgnoreCase("HTTP 401 Unauthorized")) {

            return getResourceBundleForPatient(patientId, resources);

        } else {

            throw new PatientNotFoundException("Patient Id Not Found");

        }

    }
```